# Launch failed. The app could not be launched on xamarin

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, ios-simulator

I am getting the following error when trying to run Visual Studio/Xamarin built application on the IOS Simulator.

```
Launch failed. The app 'App2' could not be launched on 'iPhone 7 Plus iOS 10.1'. Please check the logs for more details.
```

"App2" was created using the Tab Template, and NO code changes after rolling the application.

Windows environment: Windows 10 w/Visual Studio 2015 update 2

Mac environment: IMac Sierra fully patched.  XCode 8.1 (what ever is most up to date).

I have connected the mac remote and pc.  I can launch the iPhone simulator on the mac from Visual studio on the PC.

I get the error when trying to run "App2".  It compiles fine, just won't run on the simulator.

I've searched here, and similar results speak of VS Crashing.  Mine doesn't crash, just presents the error.  NOTE: There's nothing in any log I can find with details by the way.

Ideas?  Thanks!

EDIT: Just loaded up Parallels on the IMac and ran Win 10/VStudio. I get the same error.  Again, xamarin remote agent connected and I can start the simulator from the PC, i just can't deploy to it.

Comment: Did you check the logs as it asks you to?

Comment: I checked every log I could find.  Both Mac and PC. Might well not be finding the right one.

Comment: Check ˜/Library/Logs/Xamarin-4.2 there should be some build logs

Comment: @cheesebaron, thanks, but on both mac and ios i searched that.  Then I stumbled on  "Help > Xamarin > Open Logs" in VS 2015.

Found this in the log.  "Failed to launch the simulator: Could not load the framework 'libswiftos.dylib'"

Quick search on libswiftos.dylib finds this is a known bug in Xamarin.  Now to go force myself to learn enough Git to download the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the research and help from those here it comes down to a bug with the current version of Xamarin.  Options are to wait until a new stable build is on the Xamarin site or get builds off of GIT.  I'm choosing to wait, as I've not had great luck working with interim builds.

Xamarin that downloads with the new VS 2017 fixes this bug.

Comment: The bug referred to here is [45855](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45855). I had to update Xamarin for Visual Studio (on the Windows machine) to fix this. Previously had 4.2.0.703 and the fix is in 4.2.0.719.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment.  I just installed Visual Studio 2017 RC, and the Xamarin that downloaded with it, fixed the problem as well.  4.2.1.60